# R create new variable from several columns if one satisfies condition

Tags: r, design-patterns, conditional-statements

sorry for the very unspecific title. I really don't know how to name the problem... So I'm dealing with this data frame :

```
 C1 <- c("made in Italy", "100% silk", "dry clean only")
 C2 <- c("80% cotton, 20% polyester","made in France", "hand wash")
 C3 <- c("made in Italy", "Designer color : vanilla", " 100% nylon")
 eg <- as.data.frame(rbind(C1,C2,C3))
```

I'd like to add one veriable "composition" by extracting all the values containing "%" sign. As you can see, the composition values are not in the same column for each observation...
I tried several methods but failed to achieve this. 
for example :

```
 fcompo <- function(x){
   if (grepl('%',x) = TRUE){eg$composition <- paste(x)}
 else {eg$composition=NA}
 }
```

then I got lost in the function... being very new to R language...
I also tried :

```
  library(stringr)

  eg$composition <- str_extract(eg[,c(1:3)], "%$" )
```

thanks a lot for your generous help

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want one column with all the % values? What if there are multiple %s in one row?

Comment: you can do `eg$composition <- apply(eg, 1, function(x) grep("%", x, value=TRUE))` (you could have kept `eg` as matrix by the way as it's all characters)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Hello, Yes, the expected output is to have one new column with all the %values regardless of how many % one row has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `apply` with `margin=1` to keep, by row, the field with the composition (i.e. the one containing at least one "%" sign):

```
eg$composition <- apply(eg, 1, function(x) grep("%", x, value=TRUE))
eg
#                          V1                       V2             V3               composition
#C1             made in Italy                100% silk dry clean only                 100% silk
#C2 80% cotton, 20% polyester           made in France      hand wash 80% cotton, 20% polyester
#C3             made in Italy Designer color : vanilla     100% nylon                100% nylon
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `regmatches`.

```
unlist(regmatches(unlist(eg),gregexpr("\\d+%.*",unlist(eg))))
                      V1.C2                       V2.C1                       V3.C3 
"80% cotton, 20% polyester"                 "100% silk"                "100% nylon"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked on the example. but when i apply it on my data base, it returns :   replacement has 11527 rows, data has 15047. I suppose it's because a lot of rows don't have any values containing %. Would you know the solution ?

Comment: You right, there are some rows that do not contain %. That would mean looping

Comment: looping ... ? would you please give me an example ?